# Selenium IDE Test Case Pass / Fail

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am new in using `Selenium IDE`. I'm writing this test case where User A clicks this link and then it should direct the user to the correct page. Unfortunately, the page returns:

```
An error occured. Message: script 'pp/agensi-list.phtml' not found in path (C:/htdffocs/star/application/views\scripts/**)
```

But on my selenium, it shows the test case has passed (it should fail).

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it is very easy to write test case results pass/fail using selenium with testng framework,please read from below link i have given clear examples.

[How can I write Test Result (Pass/Fail) in Excel file using TestNG Framework with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964639/how-can-i-write-test-result-pass-fail-in-excel-file-using-testng-framework-wit)

For more with real time examples ,you can read [write test case pass/fail in excel using testng](https://youtu.be/2KQVXl0QDNU)

Simply you have to create Excel utility for fileinput stream and fileoutputstream classes as below and call that class into another classes using extends keyword

Excel Utility:

```
public class Excelutility {

@BeforeTest
public void exceloperation(){

FileinputStream file = new FileiinputStream("file path");
//do file input stream details here
Fileoutputstream newfile=new Fileoutputstream("filepath");
//do fileoutputstream details here like create workbook,create sheets etc
}
}
```

Another class:

```
public class operations{

@Test
public void openbrowser(){

//write driver operations here

//write excel operations using 
if(Title.equalsIgnoreCase("HP Loadrunner Tutorial")){
                Testcase="PASS";                    
        }else{
            Testcase = "FAIL";              
        }
Label l1=new Label(1,2,"status")
writablesh.addCell(l3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test is likely passing because you aren't verifying anything after the click.

If the test stops after the link is clicked then it will pass. You have to confirm that something happened. Look for a change in the CSS or perhaps even look for the message you listed above?

Comment: Thank you. But how to make the selenium shows fail instead or pass?

Comment: Have Updated my answer. Code would still be helpful